# Python jinja2 redirect with passing a parameter

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am using Google app engine and I want to redirect to another page with a parameter when a form submited.

Here is the first form:

```
<form method="post" class="form-inline pull-left">
   <div class="input-append">
     <input type="text" required name="askquestion" class="span5"/>
     <button type="submit" name="askbutton"  class="btn-u" value="askbutton">Ask</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

And here the backend:

```
askbutton = self.request.get("askbutton")
if askbutton:
  title = self.request.get("askquestion")
  self.render("makeaquestion.html",title=title)
```

I have already tried another one:

```
self.redirect("/makeaquestion?title='%s'"%title)
```

The first one render the new html and pass the parameter but the url stay the same as before. The second one redirect to the new url but without passing the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the action attribute of your form:

```
<form action="/makequestion" method="post" class="form-inline pull-left">
   <div class="input-append">
     <input type="text" required name="askquestion" class="span5"/>
     <button type="submit" name="askbutton"  class="btn-u" value="askbutton">Ask</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

This will submit a post request (with the filled-in data) to `/makequestion`

Answer (score 0):

Your second method:
     self.redirect("/makeaquestion?title='%s'"%title)
should be successful if you are pulling the params from the url in your Handler:

```
 class HandleMakeQuestion(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, params):
        title = self.request.get('title')
        logging.info("Title: %s" %(title))
```

This may also require some regex in your Handler Routing:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/makeaquestion([^/]+)', HandleMakeQuestion)])
```

Comment: Second method was a redirect which included params in the url: Get.

Comment: Correct and he wanted to pass it as POST.